# Finding indices of maximum elements of an array in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a piece of code in python to find the index or indices of the maximum element(s) in a vector. I know I could use 'argmax' to find the answer if there is only one maximum, but what if I have a vector which has two maximum values?

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where`

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,3])

np.where(a==np.max(a))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more than one index as the max value:

```
li = [2, 7, 3, 7]
max_value = max(li)
max_value_indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(li) if e == max_value]
print(max_value_indexes)
```

For singular case:

```
li = [2, 7, 3]
print(li.index(max(li)))
```

Comment: if I was looking for a way to do this for an unspecified vector, v, for example instead of a given vector, how would I define this vector? would using np.empty work?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `np.where` :

```
import numpy as np

values = [1,6,3,4,5,6,6,5]

arr_values = np.array(values, copy=False)
indices= np.where(arr_values == max(arr_values))[0]
```